# Squaring all the elements in a list by Scheme

Tags: function, scheme, racket

I wanted to square all elements in a list by the Scheme programming language.
my code is:

```lisp
(define (square n) (* n *n))

(define (fun items factor)
  (if (null? items)
      0
      (cons (* (fun (car items)
                    factor))
            (fun (cdr items)
                 factor) ) ) ) )
(display (fun '( 1 2 3 4) square))
```

I'm showing these errors:

```
ERROR: In procedure car: 
  ERROR: In procedure car: 
    Wrong type (expecting pair): 1
```

Comment: Please reformat the code. It is unreadable and has obvious silly errors like `square` referencing the global variable `*n` and to many closing parentheses after defining `fun`. You have no questions in here so I guess you posted this just to inform us?  If you pass `square` that takes one argument what do you think will happen when you call it with both `(car items)` and `factor`? Also you call `fun` on the `car` always so you expect all the elements to be lists also, not numbers. That is actally the error message you get since the element is `1` and you cannot do `(car 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of errors:

- The `square` procedure has an extra `*` that shouldn't be there
- If we're building a list as output, then the base case should return the empty list `'()`, not `0`.
- The part where you operate on the current element of the list is incorrect, you should simply call the `factor` procedure on the `car` of the list, and there's no need to multiply again, `square` will take care of that.

This should fix them:

```
(define (square n) (* n n))

(define (fun items factor)
  (if (null? items)
      '()
      (cons (factor (car items))
            (fun (cdr items) factor))))
```

In real life, you don't need to implement this procedure yourself, `map` is already built-in and it's as simple to use as this:

```
(map square '(1 2 3 4))
=> '(1 4 9 16)
```

Comment: @MuttakinAhamed1610830642 did this post solve your question? if so, please don’t forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, just click on the checkmark to its left ;) . Also worth reading: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Here is other method:

```
(define factor-list
  (lambda (l factor return)
    (if (null? l)
        (return '())
        (factor-list (cdr l)
                     factor
                     (lambda (rest)
                       (return (cons (factor (car l))
                                     rest)))))))


(define input '(1 2 3 4))
(factor-list input (lambda (x) (* x x)) (lambda (x) x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Tail recursive implementation of `map` (to not to overwrite built-in `map` I called it `*map`).

```
(define (square x) (* x x))

(define (*map func lst (acc '()))
  "Apply func on each element of the list."
  (cond ((null? lst) (reverse acc))
        (else (*map func (cdr lst) (cons (func (car lst)) acc)))))
```

Run it by:

```
(*map square '(1 2 3)) ;; '(1 4 9)
```